# UAL Assembly from C to UAL assembly

Tags: c, assembly, computer-science

Rewrite the following program in UAL assembly, given its C code. Assume that gcd()
and print() are ABI compliant functions that calculate the greatest common divider
and print the variable respectively. Make sure to annotate your assembly code

```
int main() {
uint32_t a=0x5, b, i;
b = 4*a;
while(i<10) {
b = gcd(a, b);
i++;
}
print(b);
}
```

this is for a pre-lab that i am trying to do ... thank you

Comment: not much i am confused about assembly language and the fact that most of everything is backword

Comment: 1) If you want us to help you with your homework you need to show to us that you've already put some effort into it, like post the assembly code you've already got (even if it's wrong; the point is so we can help you correct it). 2) Please reward the people who have helped you in the past and accept answers to your older questions.

Comment: no sorry i just don't have much yet.. its just that this assembly language stuff is getting me...:(

Comment: Excuse me, but what the hell is "UAL assembly", anyway? What's the exact ABI that we're discussing?

Comment: Actually, judging from your posting history, you've pretty much been using SO to get through your classes thus far.  That won't get you anywhere outside of a classroom.  If you aren't understanding the concepts of programming, there is no shame.  Many people in the world cannot code.  If you aren't grasping the logic, you might consider a different field of study.

Answer (score 8):

This does not look like a prelab. It does however look like problem 1 (worth 20 points) that was just assigned in Embedded Systems. You should take the time to learn assembly and the equivalent in C. You will struggle in the class otherwise, since Stack Overflow wont help you on your upcoming exam.... Join a study group if you are having problems with assembly, there are other student in the class dealing with the same issues as you. There is almost always students in the lab as well.

Also, UAL is a ARM Assembly syntax see link:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/BABJIHGJ.html